# Is it allowed to answer your own question after getting other answers?

Tags: discussion

So I've gathered many interesting answers in my first question.

**Is it allowed if I take a bit from each answers, then answer my own question?**

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to do this? If it's intended to detract from the other answers, I would advise against it.

Comment: Two reasons I can think of: I'm not fully satisfied with the provided answers, but can make better explanation combining available answers, or, I want to share my own version of answer, curious about what others will think about it.

Comment: You can use SEDE to find all the self answers on WorldBuilding. [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/642320/all-the-self-answers) a query I made to do this (modified from someone else's query). There's not very many, actually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, especially if you **credit** the other posts and label it as a summary post (and you can even make it community-wiki so you won’t get “credit” for it) or clearly state how it’s derivitive.

Especially if you explain that this (based on the various answers) is what you ended up *using* in your story/game/treatment/whatever.

You can find examples of such things amomg the posts, but I wouldn’t know how to begin searching for one to give concrete examples.

If you are worried, post it in the [Answer sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers) first and get feedback (or lack of anyone caring implies it will not be seen as rude) here on meta.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more sensible to keep the question up to date, without losing its scope. Adding an 'update' or 'further thoughts' can help people see what is relevant to the question, and also get an idea regarding what conclusions you have come to.